# Origins of the Yerushalmi Kaftan

Tags: minhag, history, clothing, provenance, yerushalayim-jerusalem

Among Yerushalmi Chareidim, a special dress code seems to have developed which has some features which are unique from standard Eastern Ashkenazi dress. While most Chareidim I have seen wear black coats or jackets, the Yerushalmim wear more colourful clothing: a blue-and-white striped kaftan on weekdays and a gold-and-blue one on Shabbat.*

What is the origin of the Yerushalmi kaftan and why is it colourful when most Chareidim are makpid on black or dark grey?

---

*Source, I have seen it in Me'ah Shearim and the Rova.

Comment: http://www.mishpacha.com/Browse/Article/1480/Secret-dress-Code

Comment: @GershonGold, I'm looking for a verifiable source, more along the lines of a sefer or academic work than a glossy magazine.

Comment: That is why it was placed as a comment

Comment: from what i heard the ashkanazim were wearing the same bisht(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisht_%28clothing%29) as the arabs. but i think it was the hazon ish or someone who said not to wear lavushei joyim. so they made stripes for theirs and different style. however from what it looks like is that its a bogus story. its the same exact black bekitshe just white with stripes. it seems like they took a middle eastern color set for their european clothes

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt The Chassidim actually used to wear all white every Shabbos, until a gezirah forbade Jews from wearing white on Shabbos, at which point they switched. Rabbi Nachman z"tzl actually switched back to white on a certain Shavous. The third Chabad Rebbe (Tzemach Tzedek z"tzl) lived in Jerusalem around the time of Rabbi Nachman z"tzl (i.e after the gezirah I think), so perhaps there was already chassidim there before the gezirah that just never switched.

Comment: @Hugh the 3rd Chabad Rebbe never lived in Yerushalaim. Some of his Chassidim (and of the 2nd, 1st, and of the Maggid) lived in Israel, though mostly in Teverya and Chevron

Comment: @ShmuelBrin oh, I heard that was the origin of his commonly depicted outfit (streimel with the white caftan)

Comment: @Hugh, the Yerushalmi levush is not limited to Chassidim. It is also worn by the Perushim, talmidei haGr"a who went to E"Y around 1800, and other old Ashkenazi kehillot and rabbanim, such as R' Sonnenfeld זצ”ל of the Badatz. On the other hand, many chassidim do not wear it.

Comment: I'm told it has origins in Ottoman garb. (Makes sense, given they were in charge of that land for a very long time.) Contrast with the traditional Hassidic look, which has Eastern European roots.