# What is the name of this specific religious clothing?

Tags: clothing, breslov

https://images.app.goo.gl/jpzyD7G19SnwTdKx6

Specifically the one with the stripes thats kind of like pajamas/robe

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/63853/origins-of-the-yerushalmi-kaftan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either Yerushalmi caftan or Striped Bekitche